# Defining typealias in Swift 3 for closures

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to define a type alias for a closure in swift 3 like that:

```
 public typealias URLRequestClosure = (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void
```

I get an error that I'm supposed to put underscore before the parameters' names. i.e:
 `public typealias URLRequestClosure = (_ response: URLResponse?, _ data: Data?, _ error: Error?) -> Void`
can anyone explain me why? Is it something to do with Swift 3?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't specify parameter names in closure typealias. So instead of:

```
public typealias URLRequestClosure = (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void
```

You should use:

```
public typealias URLRequestClosure = (URLResponse?, Data?, Error?) -> Void
```

Answer (score 1):

General method signature of swift is like func name(Param1 param1:param1Type, Param2 param2:param2Type) -> returnType

Since a closure is nothing but an anonymous method, same signature rules also applies for them.

While typeAliasing a closure, you have to replace parameter names (Param1, Param2) with underScore

You can specify parameter names in closure typealias

You should use underScore before parameter names.

Then it will accept parameter names

```
public typealias URLRequestClosure = (_ response: URLResponse?, _ Data data: Data?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
```

Comment: Read the question please